# Batch script can't pass variable's contents to other variables

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm making a script for fun that identifies all computers on a network. The part I'm running into issues with is capturing the relevant ip addresses of local computers from the ARP table.
There's a function that should allow me to truncate the results and compair them to a subnet to see if the address is relevant, but when I try and handle the variables it doesn't assign anything to any of the variables and acts like all variables are empty.

Below is a truncated version of the script:

```
SET SUB="192.168.10"
SET count=1
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`arp -a`) DO (
    SET Foo=%%F
    SET Faa=%Foo%
    SET Foo=%Foo:~0,15%
    SET Faa=%Faa:~0,11%
    IF /I "!Faa!"=="%SUB%" ECHO %Foo% >> comp_list.txt
    SET /a count=!count!+1
)
```

The output of the last line of the loop in cmd is as follows:

```
C:\_Scripts\>(
SET Foo=255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
SET Faa=""
SET Foo=""
SET Faa=""
IF !Faa! == "" ECHO %Foo% >> comp_list.txt
SET /a count=!count!+1
)
```

Comment: First of all arp table contains only the addresses that the conputer has already communicated with. And only for a short amount of time. There us a trick you can use to male them all respond as one: ping the broadcast address of your network. You wont get any response directly, but the arp table will be populated.

Comment: So you're trying to get a number of how many addresses there are? That are valid? It's kinda unclear in my eyes

Comment: You are changing variable content within a loop, so you'll need to delay variable expansion on your `SET` statements too. `SET "Faa=!Foo!"`,  `SET "Foo=!Foo:~,15!` and `SET "Faa=!Faa:~,11!"`. But you could prevent some of that by using a space as a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use substring substitution. It's unreliable (as each IP element may have 1, 2 or 3 digits) Also you don't need to check each entry for the correct subnet - just filter the output of `arp -a` - that's much faster:

```
SET "SUB=146.254.181."
SET count=0
for /f %%a in ('arp -a^|find "%sub%"') do (
  set /a count+=1 
  >> "comp_list.txt" echo IP:%%a    Subnet: %%~na
)
>>"comp_list.txt" echo Sum: %count%
```

Comment: When implementing this is get either "The system cannot find the file `arp." or "File not found - [current value of %SUB%]"

Comment: use the correct quotes: (`'`) or (``` together with `usebackq`)